# Is this a safe way to mass assign through the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I decided to take a different approach to mass assigning for security reasons and wanted to know if this is a safe way to do it inside of the controller?

```
QuestionsController

def new
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
  @question = Question.new
end

def create
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
  @question = @survey.questions.new
  @question.title = params[:question][:title]
  @question.description = params[:question][:description]


  if @question.save
    redirect_to new_survey_question_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Can they change the `survey_id` or any other column of the `question`? Is their a better approach besides using `attr_accessible`?

Comment: What's wrong with attr_accessible? It should do what you want

Comment: @iwiznia I have a lot of other fields that `questions` uses but are only available in certain parts of the application but even if you take them off the form a hacker can still get to them so I assign them in the controller instead to make sure the specific ones are being past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you could do something like..

```
enabled_attributes = [:title, :description]
params[:question].delete_if {|k, v| !enabled_attributes.include?(k) }
@question = @survey.questions.new(params[:question])
```

This deletes from the params[:question] hash all the attributes that aren't in the enabled array.

Comment: Yeah, it's basically the same, but this is shorter and you could easily put it in a method of the model or a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

```
@question.title, @question.description = 
  params[:question].values_at(:title, :description)
```

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby 1.9, you can use the select method to slightly simplify iwiznia's solution.

```
enabled_attributes = [:title, :description] 
@question = @survey.questions.new(params[:question].
              select {|k, v| enabled_attributes.include?(k)})
```